# How to categorize rest of the array values into one of their common value in multidimensional array in PHP?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, foreach, count, duplicates

I have the following data in array:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [order-id] => 000509171907293
        [order-item-id] => 74
        [product-id] => 14
        [product-title] => banana
        [product-image] => 110.224.215.220_11965-sunny-deol-giving-salute-to-indian-army._2017-05-17_20:01:52.jpg
        [product-quantity] => 11
        [cod-opted] => no
        [shipment-status] => To be shipped
        [status-remarks] => 
        [tracking-id] => 
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [order-id] => 000509171907293
        [order-item-id] => 75
        [product-id] => 13
        [product-title] => bread and butter
        [product-image] => 110.224.215.220_917566930566._2017-05-17_20:24:33.jpg
        [product-quantity] => 5
        [cod-opted] => no
        [shipment-status] => To be shipped
        [status-remarks] => 
        [tracking-id] => 
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [order-id] => 000509171907293
        [order-item-id] => 76
        [product-id] => 12
        [product-title] => milk cake 
        [product-image] => 110.224.215.220_FB Profile Pic._2017-05-17_20:03:23.jpg
        [product-quantity] => 6
        [cod-opted] => no
        [shipment-status] => To be shipped
        [status-remarks] => 
        [tracking-id] => 
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [order-id] => 000509171909563
        [order-item-id] => 77
        [product-id] => 12
        [product-title] => milk cake 
        [product-image] => 110.224.215.220_FB Profile Pic._2017-05-17_20:03:23.jpg
        [product-quantity] => 1
        [cod-opted] => no
        [shipment-status] => To be shipped
        [status-remarks] => 
        [tracking-id] => 
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [order-id] => 000509171911113
        [order-item-id] => 78
        [product-id] => 13
        [product-title] => bread and butter
        [product-image] => 110.224.215.220_917566930566._2017-05-17_20:24:33.jpg
        [product-quantity] => 1
        [cod-opted] => yes
        [shipment-status] => To be shipped
        [status-remarks] => 
        [tracking-id] => 
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [order-id] => 000509171914543
        [order-item-id] => 79
        [product-id] => 15
        [product-title] => Kocra
        [product-image] => 110.224.215.220_1._2017-05-17_19:38:57.jpg
        [product-quantity] => 6
        [cod-opted] => no
        [shipment-status] => To be shipped
        [status-remarks] => 
        [tracking-id] => 
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [order-id] => 000509171914543
        [order-item-id] => 80
        [product-id] => 14
        [product-title] => banana
        [product-image] => 110.224.215.220_11965-sunny-deol-giving-salute-to-indian-army._2017-05-17_20:01:52.jpg
        [product-quantity] => 4
        [cod-opted] => no
        [shipment-status] => To be shipped
        [status-remarks] => 
        [tracking-id] => 
    )

[7] => Array
    (
        [order-id] => 000509171914543
        [order-item-id] => 81
        [product-id] => 13
        [product-title] => bread and butter
        [product-image] => 110.224.215.220_917566930566._2017-05-17_20:24:33.jpg
        [product-quantity] => 3
        [cod-opted] => no
        [shipment-status] => To be shipped
        [status-remarks] => 
        [tracking-id] => 
    )

[8] => Array
    (
        [order-id] => 000509171914543
        [order-item-id] => 82
        [product-id] => 12
        [product-title] => milk cake 
        [product-image] => 110.224.215.220_FB Profile Pic._2017-05-17_20:03:23.jpg
        [product-quantity] => 13
        [cod-opted] => no
        [shipment-status] => To be shipped
        [status-remarks] => 
        [tracking-id] => 
    )

[9] => Array
    (
        [order-id] => 000509171927293
        [order-item-id] => 83
        [product-id] => 13
        [product-title] => bread and butter
        [product-image] => 110.224.215.220_917566930566._2017-05-17_20:24:33.jpg
        [product-quantity] => 1
        [cod-opted] => no
        [shipment-status] => To be shipped
        [status-remarks] => 
        [tracking-id] => 
    )

[10] => Array
    (
        [order-id] => 000609171310503
        [order-item-id] => 84
        [product-id] => 13
        [product-title] => bread and butter
        [product-image] => 110.224.215.220_917566930566._2017-05-17_20:24:33.jpg
        [product-quantity] => 1
        [cod-opted] => no
        [shipment-status] => To be shipped
        [status-remarks] => 
        [tracking-id] => 
    )

[11] => Array
    (
        [order-id] => 000609171310503
        [order-item-id] => 85
        [product-id] => 12
        [product-title] => milk cake 
        [product-image] => 110.224.215.220_FB Profile Pic._2017-05-17_20:03:23.jpg
        [product-quantity] => 4
        [cod-opted] => no
        [shipment-status] => To be shipped
        [status-remarks] => 
        [tracking-id] => 
    )

[12] => Array
    (
        [order-id] => 000609172015453
        [order-item-id] => 86
        [product-id] => 12
        [product-title] => milk cake 
        [product-image] => 110.224.215.220_FB Profile Pic._2017-05-17_20:03:23.jpg
        [product-quantity] => 1
        [cod-opted] => no
        [shipment-status] => To be shipped
        [status-remarks] => 
        [tracking-id] => 
    )

[13] => Array
    (
        [order-id] => 000809170448333
        [order-item-id] => 87
        [product-id] => 12
        [product-title] => milk cake 
        [product-image] => 110.224.215.220_FB Profile Pic._2017-05-17_20:03:23.jpg
        [product-quantity] => 5
        [cod-opted] => no
        [shipment-status] => To be shipped
        [status-remarks] => 
        [tracking-id] => 
    )

[14] => Array
    (
        [order-id] => 000809171253383
        [order-item-id] => 88
        [product-id] => 12
        [product-title] => milk cake 
        [product-image] => 110.224.215.220_FB Profile Pic._2017-05-17_20:03:23.jpg
        [product-quantity] => 5
        [cod-opted] => no
        [shipment-status] => To be shipped
        [status-remarks] => 
        [tracking-id] => 
    )

[15] => Array
    (
        [order-id] => 0001108170117183
        [order-item-id] => 44
        [product-id] => 16
        [product-title] => Lettuce
        [product-image] => 190.83.252.216_5091493+_e4554c4aa8bcadca050a8ccd960cf22b._2017-05-19_17:55:00.jpg
        [product-quantity] => 8
        [cod-opted] => no
        [shipment-status] => Dispatched
        [status-remarks] => 
        [tracking-id] => 0
    )

[16] => Array
    (
        [order-id] => 0001407171017583
        [order-item-id] => 38
        [product-id] => 17
        [product-title] => Bread
        [product-image] => 190.83.252.216_buffet-salatvariationen._2017-05-26_23:32:10.jpg
        [product-quantity] => 9
        [cod-opted] => no
        [shipment-status] => To be shipped
        [status-remarks] => 
        [tracking-id] => 
    )

[17] => Array
    (
        [order-id] => 0001407171017583
        [order-item-id] => 39
        [product-id] => 16
        [product-title] => Lettuce
        [product-image] => 190.83.252.216_5091493+_e4554c4aa8bcadca050a8ccd960cf22b._2017-05-19_17:55:00.jpg
        [product-quantity] => 27
        [cod-opted] => no
        [shipment-status] => To be shipped
        [status-remarks] => 
        [tracking-id] => 
    )

[18] => Array
    (
        [order-id] => 0001407171017583
        [order-item-id] => 40
        [product-id] => 6
        [product-title] => Patatoes
        [product-image] => 190.83.252.216_Russet-Potatoes-cut._2017-05-15_01:49:06.jpg
        [product-quantity] => 14
        [cod-opted] => no
        [shipment-status] => To be shipped
        [status-remarks] => 
        [tracking-id] => 
    )

[19] => Array
    (
        [order-id] => 0001708170015173
        [order-item-id] => 48
        [product-id] => 12
        [product-title] => milk cake 
        [product-image] => 110.224.215.220_FB Profile Pic._2017-05-17_20:03:23.jpg
        [product-quantity] => 1
        [cod-opted] => no
        [shipment-status] => To be shipped
        [status-remarks] => 
        [tracking-id] => 
    )

[20] => Array
    (
        [order-id] => 0001708170103063
        [order-item-id] => 49
        [product-id] => 12
        [product-title] => milk cake 
        [product-image] => 110.224.215.220_FB Profile Pic._2017-05-17_20:03:23.jpg
        [product-quantity] => 5
        [cod-opted] => no
        [shipment-status] => To be shipped
        [status-remarks] => 
        [tracking-id] => 
    )

[21] => Array
    (
        [order-id] => 0002308170529513
        [order-item-id] => 50
        [product-id] => 12
        [product-title] => milk cake 
        [product-image] => 110.224.215.220_FB Profile Pic._2017-05-17_20:03:23.jpg
        [product-quantity] => 1
        [cod-opted] => no
        [shipment-status] => To be shipped
        [status-remarks] => 
        [tracking-id] => 
    )

[22] => Array
    (
        [order-id] => 0002308170529513
        [order-item-id] => 51
        [product-id] => 13
        [product-title] => bread and butter
        [product-image] => 110.224.215.220_917566930566._2017-05-17_20:24:33.jpg
        [product-quantity] => 1
        [cod-opted] => no
        [shipment-status] => To be shipped
        [status-remarks] => 
        [tracking-id] => 
    )

[23] => Array
    (
        [order-id] => 0003108171650493
        [order-item-id] => 52
        [product-id] => 12
        [product-title] => milk cake 
        [product-image] => 110.224.215.220_FB Profile Pic._2017-05-17_20:03:23.jpg
        [product-quantity] => 7
        [cod-opted] => no
        [shipment-status] => To be shipped
        [status-remarks] => 
        [tracking-id] => 
    )

[24] => Array
    (
        [order-id] => 0003108171650493
        [order-item-id] => 53
        [product-id] => 13
        [product-title] => bread and butter
        [product-image] => 110.224.215.220_917566930566._2017-05-17_20:24:33.jpg
        [product-quantity] => 4
        [cod-opted] => no
        [shipment-status] => To be shipped
        [status-remarks] => 
        [tracking-id] => 
    )

[25] => Array
    (
        [order-id] => 0003108171650493
        [order-item-id] => 54
        [product-id] => 14
        [product-title] => banana
        [product-image] => 110.224.215.220_11965-sunny-deol-giving-salute-to-indian-army._2017-05-17_20:01:52.jpg
        [product-quantity] => 6
        [cod-opted] => no
        [shipment-status] => To be shipped
        [status-remarks] => 
        [tracking-id] => 
    )

[26] => Array
    (
        [order-id] => 0003108171650493
        [order-item-id] => 55
        [product-id] => 15
        [product-title] => Kocra
        [product-image] => 110.224.215.220_1._2017-05-17_19:38:57.jpg
        [product-quantity] => 8
        [cod-opted] => no
        [shipment-status] => To be shipped
        [status-remarks] => 
        [tracking-id] => 
    )

[27] => Array
    (
        [order-id] => 0003108171650493
        [order-item-id] => 56
        [product-id] => 19
        [product-title] => test
        [product-image] => 171.60.145.34_eggs_small._2017-06-02_17:57:07.jpeg
        [product-quantity] => 10
        [cod-opted] => no
        [shipment-status] => To be shipped
        [status-remarks] => 
        [tracking-id] => 
    )

[28] => Array
    (
        [order-id] => 0003108171650493
        [order-item-id] => 57
        [product-id] => 18
        [product-title] => test
        [product-image] => 171.60.145.34_eggs_small._2017-06-02_17:57:07.jpeg
        [product-quantity] => 8
        [cod-opted] => no
        [shipment-status] => To be shipped
        [status-remarks] => 
        [tracking-id] => 
    )

[29] => Array
    (
        [order-id] => 0003108171713463
        [order-item-id] => 58
        [product-id] => 12
        [product-title] => milk cake 
        [product-image] => 110.224.215.220_FB Profile Pic._2017-05-17_20:03:23.jpg
        [product-quantity] => 1
        [cod-opted] => yes
        [shipment-status] => To be shipped
        [status-remarks] => 
        [tracking-id] => 
    )

[30] => Array
    (
        [order-id] => 0003108171713463
        [order-item-id] => 59
        [product-id] => 13
        [product-title] => bread and butter
        [product-image] => 110.224.215.220_917566930566._2017-05-17_20:24:33.jpg
        [product-quantity] => 1
        [cod-opted] => yes
        [shipment-status] => To be shipped
        [status-remarks] => 
        [tracking-id] => 
    )

[31] => Array
    (
        [order-id] => 0003108171713463
        [order-item-id] => 60
        [product-id] => 15
        [product-title] => Kocra
        [product-image] => 110.224.215.220_1._2017-05-17_19:38:57.jpg
        [product-quantity] => 1
        [cod-opted] => yes
        [shipment-status] => To be shipped
        [status-remarks] => 
        [tracking-id] => 
    )

[32] => Array
    (
        [order-id] => 0003108171713463
        [order-item-id] => 61
        [product-id] => 14
        [product-title] => banana
        [product-image] => 110.224.215.220_11965-sunny-deol-giving-salute-to-indian-army._2017-05-17_20:01:52.jpg
        [product-quantity] => 1
        [cod-opted] => yes
        [shipment-status] => To be shipped
        [status-remarks] => 
        [tracking-id] => 
    )

[33] => Array
    (
        [order-id] => 0003108171720573
        [order-item-id] => 62
        [product-id] => 12
        [product-title] => milk cake 
        [product-image] => 110.224.215.220_FB Profile Pic._2017-05-17_20:03:23.jpg
        [product-quantity] => 1
        [cod-opted] => yes
        [shipment-status] => To be shipped
        [status-remarks] => 
        [tracking-id] => 
    )

[34] => Array
    (
        [order-id] => 0003108171733353
        [order-item-id] => 63
        [product-id] => 12
        [product-title] => milk cake 
        [product-image] => 110.224.215.220_FB Profile Pic._2017-05-17_20:03:23.jpg
        [product-quantity] => 1
        [cod-opted] => yes
        [shipment-status] => To be shipped
        [status-remarks] => 
        [tracking-id] => 
    )

[35] => Array
    (
        [order-id] => 0003108171733353
        [order-item-id] => 64
        [product-id] => 13
        [product-title] => bread and butter
        [product-image] => 110.224.215.220_917566930566._2017-05-17_20:24:33.jpg
        [product-quantity] => 1
        [cod-opted] => yes
        [shipment-status] => To be shipped
        [status-remarks] => 
        [tracking-id] => 
    )

[36] => Array
    (
        [order-id] => 0003108171733353
        [order-item-id] => 65
        [product-id] => 14
        [product-title] => banana
        [product-image] => 110.224.215.220_11965-sunny-deol-giving-salute-to-indian-army._2017-05-17_20:01:52.jpg
        [product-quantity] => 1
        [cod-opted] => yes
        [shipment-status] => To be shipped
        [status-remarks] => 
        [tracking-id] => 
    )

[37] => Array
    (
        [order-id] => 0003108171733353
        [order-item-id] => 66
        [product-id] => 15
        [product-title] => Kocra
        [product-image] => 110.224.215.220_1._2017-05-17_19:38:57.jpg
        [product-quantity] => 1
        [cod-opted] => yes
        [shipment-status] => To be shipped
        [status-remarks] => 
        [tracking-id] => 
    )

[38] => Array
    (
        [order-id] => 0003108171733353
        [order-item-id] => 67
        [product-id] => 18
        [product-title] => test
        [product-image] => 171.60.145.34_eggs_small._2017-06-02_17:57:07.jpeg
        [product-quantity] => 1
        [cod-opted] => yes
        [shipment-status] => To be shipped
        [status-remarks] => 
        [tracking-id] => 
    )

[39] => Array
    (
        [order-id] => 0003108171733353
        [order-item-id] => 68
        [product-id] => 19
        [product-title] => test
        [product-image] => 171.60.145.34_eggs_small._2017-06-02_17:57:07.jpeg
        [product-quantity] => 1
        [cod-opted] => yes
        [shipment-status] => To be shipped
        [status-remarks] => 
        [tracking-id] => 
    )

[40] => Array
    (
        [order-id] => 0003108171733353
        [order-item-id] => 69
        [product-id] => 20
        [product-title] => New Chinese Eggs
        [product-image] => 171.60.145.34_a-bowl-full-of-brown-eggs._2017-06-02_19:56:09.jpg
        [product-quantity] => 1
        [cod-opted] => yes
        [shipment-status] => To be shipped
        [status-remarks] => 
        [tracking-id] => 
    )

[41] => Array
    (
        [order-id] => 0003108171733353
        [order-item-id] => 70
        [product-id] => 21
        [product-title] => Okra
        [product-image] => 171.60.145.34_admin_pic_facebook._2017-06-02_20:13:18.jpg
        [product-quantity] => 7
        [cod-opted] => yes
        [shipment-status] => To be shipped
        [status-remarks] => 
        [tracking-id] => 
    )

)
```

Now if you notice `order-id` is common/duplicate in many sub-arrays, but rest of the values in those sub-arrays are different, I want to categorize rest of the values in each sub-array and display it under one duplicate/common `order-id`, how can I do so?

What I did so far (with many versions) is the following:

```
print '<div id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">';
    $accordion_collapse_count = 1;
    $order_id_check_duplicates = array();

    foreach($order_details_uncategorized as $single_order_details){

            if (!in_array($single_order_details['order-id'], $order_id_check_duplicates)){

                print '<div class="panel panel-default">';
               print  '<div class="panel-heading">';

                      print '<h4 class="panel-title">
                              <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse'.$accordion_collapse_count.'">ORDER ID: '.$single_order_details['order-id'].'</a>
                            </h4>';

                print '</div>';

                 print  '<div id="collapse'.$accordion_collapse_count.'" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                            <div class="panel-body">';
            }

                            print '<span class="repeat-this">'.$single_order_details['order-item-id'].'</span><br>';
                            print $single_order_details['order-id'].'<br>';

            if (!in_array($single_order_details['order-id'], $order_id_check_duplicates)){

                      print '</div>
                         </div>
                   </div>';
            }

        $accordion_collapse_count++;

        array_push($order_id_check_duplicates, $single_order_details['order-id']);
    }

    print '</div>';
```

In the code above, I have to print all html of accordion only once, as there are duplicate order ids are available, and html with class `repeat-this` should be printed multiple times, but that's not happening.

Comment: What if values are null? Do they get duplicated and removed to separate keys?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps iterate through that array and group your results per that common value. Something like this:

```
foreach ($array as $item){
    $result[$item['order-id']][] = $item;
}
var_dump($result);
```